# ¿Como iniciar Timer sin hacer clic en un botón con Visual Basic?

Tags: vb, visual, basic

Necesito iniciar un Timer sin la necesidad de hacer clic en un botón, es decir que inicie automáticamente de acuerdo a una condición que yo le indique.

Answer (score 1):

En la propiedades del timer en compartamiento ponle Enable = True, con eso el timer iniciara al abrir el formulario donde se encuentra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]